# Mongoose - Error: 'CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ name: 'RandomName' }" at path "authors"'

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database

Error:
'CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ name: 'RandomName' }" at path "authors"'

I am using post man to do a put request to a book, which I have the _id of. I am sending a body with key value pair of name: "whateverName".

The goal is for books to have many authors in an array, on a property of each book called 'authors'.

Here is the controller.

`app.put("/book/update/:id", function(req, res) {
      var author = req.body;
      Book.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id}, {$push: {authors: author}}, {new: true}, function(err, book) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          console.log("author inserted");
          res.status(200).send();
        }
      })
    })`

Here is the Author schema.

```

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var AuthorSchema = new Schema({
  name: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Author", AuthorSchema);
```

```

Here is the Book schema.

```

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var BookSchema = new Schema({
  title: String,
  author: String,
  category: String,
  authors: [{type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: "Author"}]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Book", BookSchema);
```

```

Why is it giving me such a hard time on my day off? Can someone please tell me what gives? I just simply want to push a new author (which is it's own model) to a specific book using a reference.

Thanks so much :)

Comment: In BookSchema field 'authors' is type of 'Schema.ObjectId' but you are passing string. That's why the error showing

Comment: Should it instead look like - authors: [AuthorSchema]  ?

Answer (score 1):

Solution: You've got to create the AUTHOR instance first, then inside of that function, use the return value of the author to find a book, and update it via pushing that newly created author's id to the array.

`app.put("/book/update/:id", function(req, res) {
      Author.create(req.body, function(err, author) {
        Book.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id}, {$push: {authors: author._id}}, {upsert: true}, function(err, book) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
          } else {
            console.log("author inserted");
            res.status(200).send();
          }
        })
      })
    })`

Comment: But the best method is create the author first. i.e, maintain a separate page for adding new authors. Then in the book adding section  from a list you can add the authors related with the book. Otherwise you face data redundancy.

Comment: Another case if you want to find all book related with a specific author. Then it is not possible with your code.

Comment: I edited my answers which solves all the above commented issues

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are storing author's _id in the book authors array.
So you need to pass the author data as like this [{array of _id's}]

```
app.put("/book/update/:id", function(req, res) {
  /***************************/
  var author = req.body; // array of _id (ObjectId)
  /***************************/
  Book.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id}, {$push: {authors: author}}, {new: true}, function(err, book) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log("author inserted");
        res.status(200).send();
      }
   })
})
```

Comment: But how would I do that? I don't even know what the ID is....I'm intending to CREATE the author right there on the spot...

Comment: You already have a list of authors right ? While you creating a book you are adding author to that book section right?

Comment: No. I have zero authors. I am intending to be on a BOOK's show page, and on the show page you can type in a single input an author's name. Each time you submit, a new author instance will be added to the 'authors' array in the book.

Comment: Do I have to create the author instance first? If so... How would I do so from the book show page? I.e. 1) submit the form with the author name 2) in the controller, create new book, then 3) string a promise to findOneAndUpdate to update the book and push the id of the new author in? How would I do that in the controller?

Comment: Ok then you need to save the author data first in 'authors' collection and from the response you get the _id. Use that _id to store authors data in 'book' collection

Comment: Thank you, would you be able to update your code comment above to show how this would look?

Comment: difference between 'author' and 'authors' ?

Comment: Nvm I got it. Author was just something totally unrelated. Wanted to push to AuthorS. Solution: Author.create(req.body, function(err, author) {
    Book.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id}, {$push: {authors: author._id}}, {upsert: true}, function(err, book) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log("author inserted");
        res.status(200).send();
      }
    })
  })

Comment: Cool. Iam just confused. That's why ask the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124472/discussion-between-ti2005-and-tyler).